# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Error is occuring in the Hibernateutil.java file while loading the Hibernate.cfg.xml file

sample input and generated stack of errors.

```
Apr 26, 2023 12:01:25 PM com.infybank.ClientDemo main
INFO: Enter the Customer details
Enter the Customer name
Drona
Enter the Customer date of birth in MM/dd/yyyy format
03/05/2003
Enter the Customer address
Mahadevapalli
Enter the Customer phoneNo
7997776865
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at jboss.logging@3.3.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at jboss.logging@3.3.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at jboss.logging@3.3.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at hibernate.core@5.2.11.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at hibernate.core@5.2.11.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at hibernate.core@5.2.11.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:85)
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.CustomerDAO.addCustomer(CustomerDAO.java:11)
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.ClientDemo.main(ClientDemo.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more
Apr 26, 2023 12:01:44 PM com.infybank.HibernateUtil <clinit>
ERROR: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:23)
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.CustomerDAO.addCustomer(CustomerDAO.java:11)
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.ClientDemo.main(ClientDemo.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/SystemException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at jboss.logging@3.3.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2554)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at jboss.logging@3.3.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2529)
    at jboss.logging@3.3.0.Final/org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2516)
    at hibernate.core@5.2.11.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:28)
    at hibernate.core@5.2.11.Final/org.hibernate.internal.CoreLogging.messageLogger(CoreLogging.java:24)
    at hibernate.core@5.2.11.Final/org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:85)
    at CUSTOMER_DEMO/com.infybank.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.transaction.SystemException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 13 more
```

I am using eclipse-ide-2023.

Java version : javaSE-19

I have taken the libraries from the hibernate-search-5.8.0.Final-dist.

The below is the directory structure of my project.

[Files and Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7arV.png)

These are the project files.

Customer.java

```
package com.infybank;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMER")
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMERID")
    int customerId;
    @Column(name = "CUSTOMERNAME")
    String customerName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATEOFBIRTH")
    Date dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    String address;
    @Column(name = "PHONENO")
    Long phoneNo;

    public Customer() {
        super();
    }

    public Customer(String customerName, Date dateOfBirth, String address, Long phoneNo) {

        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Long getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(Long phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }
}
```

CustomerDAO.java

```
package com.infybank;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class CustomerDAO implements ICustomer {

    /* Method to create customer record */
    @Override
    public void addCustomer(Customer c1) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(c1);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
                                                                       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Mysql@272</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.infybank.Customer" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package com.infybank;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class HibernateUtil {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {

        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("/CUSTOMER_DEMO/src/com/infybank/Hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties())
                    .build();
            sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

module-info.java

```
/**
 * 
 */
/**
 * @author Drona
 *
 */
module CUSTOMER_DEMO {
    requires dom4j;
    requires hibernate.core;
    requires hibernate.jpa;
    requires jboss.logging;
}
```

ClientDemo.java

```
package com.infybank;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

public class ClientDemo {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClientDemo.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomerDAO customerdao = new CustomerDAO();
        try {
            logger.info("Enter the Customer details");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the Customer name");
            String name = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the Customer date of birth in MM/dd/yyyy format");
            String datestr = sc.next();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
            Date dob = formatter.parse(datestr);
            System.out.println("Enter the Customer address");
            String address = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the Customer phoneNo");
            Long phone = sc.nextLong();
            Customer customer = new Customer(name, dob, address, phone);
            customerdao.addCustomer(customer);
            logger.info("One record created");
            sc.close();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using different combinations of the jar files but nothing worked.

I have searched the stackoverflow also for relevant questions but couldn't find the solution.

This is the table in the database.

[customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIarV.png)

[Table Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZm7r.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check those guide for asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  have you considered using maven or gradle to manage dependencies in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **javax.transaction: javax.transaction-api.jar**
The best would be to start using maven/gradle to handle your dependencies, because after you fix this error, new errors might come along.
After creating a pom.xml you can simply add dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```